# Find a name a of YouTube video from a deleted account

Tags: youtube

I keep some pretty rare music tracks that can't be found anywhere else on a 'not-on-Spotify' playlist on YouTube.

I just figured out today that a video of this playlist has been removed (user account has been deleted actually).

Here is the link I still can see on the playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkdVDF96v5A

I have tried to:

- Google it
- Search it on: http://keepvid.com
- Search for it on TheWaybackMachine: https://archive.org/web/

No results. I'm really desperate, that really pisses me off. Any other idea might be  of great help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkdVDF96v5A

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Searching for just the videoID](https://www.google.com/search?q=bkdVDF96v5A&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr), it appears that the title in question is "Mick jenkins on the map".

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot! That was it: "Mick Jenkins - On The Map (feat. BADBADNOTGOOD)": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nd9-jo_b1U